# Are Street Fighter 4 stages different sizes?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv, street-fighter-iv

**Is there a mechanical difference between the stages in Street Fighter 4?**

At first glance, they seem to be identical in all but graphical elements and aesthetics.  However, I have heard numerous claims that some stages are actually shorter or longer than others.  This has always seemed unlikely to me, but I can't deny that it's possible.  What is the truth in the matter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a common myth, but no, all of the stages in Street Fighter 4 are the exact same length. This has been [verified](http://forums.shoryuken.com/discussion/comment/6060331/#Comment_6060331) [independently](http://forums.shoryuken.com/discussion/comment/5836649/#Comment_5836649) by multiple players by frame-counting how long it takes a given character to walk across each stage, as well as [by comparing move properties with known ranges](http://forums.shoryuken.com/discussion/comment/6066073/#Comment_6066073). In all cases, the values are identical across all stages for a given character.

It's also possible for anyone with access to 60fps video capture equipment to fact-check this data using the same methods.